# Macro with variable length list as an argument

Tags: macros, xetex

I have a book which includes lots of circular diagrams generated using TikZ.  This is being compiled using XeLaTeX (and I specifically *don't* want to switch to LuaTeX).  To simplify the code for these diagrams, I have a series of macros which could be simplified to the following:

```
\newcommand\CircArcTwo[2]{
  \draw[->] (1) to[bend left=#1] (2);
  \draw[->] (2) to[bend left=#2] (1);
}

\newcommand\CircArcThree[3]{
  \draw[->] (1) to[bend left=#1] (2);
  \draw[->] (2) to[bend left=#2] (3);
  \draw[->] (3) to[bend left=#3] (1);
}
```

... and so on, currently all the way to `\CircArcSeven`.  The point is that they draw arcs link *n* nodes: 1 → 2 → 3 → ... → *n* → 1.  The TikZ details are not particularly relevant to this question, and in reality are more complex than what I've shown.  The nodes could easily be renamed if that makes life easier.

A MWE using this is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\CircArcThree[3]{
  \draw[->] (1) to[bend left=#1] (2);
  \draw[->] (2) to[bend left=#2] (3);
  \draw[->] (3) to[bend left=#3] (1);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) at (90:1) {Foo};
  \node (2) at (345:1) {Bar};
  \node (3) at (195:1) {Baz};
  \CircArcThree{32}{55}{32}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a good way of writing this as a single macro which takes a variable number of arguments, or which somehow takes a list as its argument, so instead of writing `\CircArcThree{32}{55}{32}` I can use a single macro and maybe write `\CircArc{32,55,32}`?

I don't care exactly what the syntax is; my primary aim to remove duplication of code, as I recently discovered an error in one of the arc definitions in my `\CircArcSix` macro, which is the least used of the set.

Comment: use a comma list not {}{}{}{} there are many macros to iterate over such a list, some built in to latex, but as you are using tikz, its `\foreach` is probably what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to David Carlisle for suggesting I use `\foreach`.  This seems to be a working solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{arccount}
\newcommand\CircArc[1]{
  \setcounter{arccount}{0}
  \foreach \x in {#1}{\stepcounter{arccount}}
  \foreach \x [count=\n from 1] in {#1}{
    \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\n,\thearccount)+1)}
    \draw[->] (\n) to[bend left=\x] (\pgfmathresult);
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) at (90:1) {Foo};
  \node (2) at (345:1) {Bar};
  \node (3) at (195:1) {Baz};
  \CircArc{32,55,32}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To me, this seems a lot clearer than the LaTeX3-based solution, though that may simply be my lack of experience with LaTeX3 functionality.  It seems a little inelegant that I need to define a counter simply to get the length of a list, but it's a simple enough solution.

Comment: You can use `\pgfmathsetmacro\arccount{dim{{#1}}` and `\arccount` will contain the number of items.

Comment: @egreg – thanks.  I didn't know about the `dim` function.  Using that, I can just write `\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\n,dim({#1}))+1)}` and then I don't need `arccount` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can be done with `\foreach`, but I'm more at ease with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\CircArc{m}
 {
  \richard_circarc:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \richard_circarc:n
 {
  % split the list into a sequence
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__richard_circarc_seq { #1 }
  % clear the tl containing the body
  \tl_clear:N \l__richard_circarc_tl
  % add the arcs
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__richard_circarc_seq \__richard_circarc_make:nn
  % deliver the result
  \tl_use:N \l__richard_circarc_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__richard_circarc_make:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 = \seq_count:N \l__richard_circarc_seq }
   {% we're at the last arc, we need to go back to 1
    \__richard_circarc_make_aux:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
   }
   {% we're in the middle, go to the next node
    \__richard_circarc_make_aux:nen { #1 } { \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } } { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__richard_circarc_make_aux:nnn
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__richard_circarc_tl
   {
    \draw[->]~(#1)~to~[bend~left=#3]~(#2);
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__richard_circarc_make_aux:nnn { ne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) at (90:1) {Foo};
  \node (2) at (345:1) {Bar};
  \node (3) at (195:1) {Baz};
  \CircArc{32,55,32}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (1) at (90:1) {Foo};
  \node (2) at (0:1) {Bar};
  \node (3) at (270:1) {Baz};
  \node (4) at (180:1) {Gnu};
  \CircArc{32,32,32,32}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm really not familiar with expl3, but it looks pretty powerful.  Is it considered fairly stable?  'Wrapper package for experimental LaTeX3' makes me wonder whether it might change underneath me.

Comment: @richard that name is historic, `expl3` is under active development, but at this stage can be considered stable, and the main parts are stable for quite a few years now.

Answer (score 1):

The following implements an automated routine that not only draws your arcs from a list of arguments, but also places the nodes, named `\circarc`.

The syntax uses a key=value list with the keys being the node texts, and the values being yet another key=value list. In that second list the following keys are available:

- `bend` the value given to `bend left`
- `angle` the angle at which the node is placed (else determined automatically)
- `radius` the radius at which the node is placed
- `style` can contain Ti*k*Z keys which are given to the `\node`
- `ccw` rotate counter-clockwise (doesn't take a value)
- `cw` rotate clockwise (doesn't take a value)

Additionally you can use `angle += <num>` or `angle -= <num>` to give an offset to the automatically calculated angle.

All these keys can also be given in an optional to `\circarc`, the only difference is that `angle` there means the angle of the first node (the others are then placed automatically relative to that, the default for this start angle is 0°, as `\circarc@angle` is empty initially, in this usage the `+` or `-` notation makes no difference). You can also give the `bend` in a short notation: Any element in the key=value list without an equals sign is interpreted as a `bend` (except for `cw` and `ccw`).

The nodes are named `circarc-<n>` with `<n>` the index in the key=value list starting at 0.

This uses `expkv` for personal preferences (disclaimer: I'm the author), but you could set up the keys with `pgfkeys` as well, of course. Though `expkv`'s `\ekvparse` is required for the parsing of the top-level list (you could use `expl3`'s `\keyval_parse:NNn` instead).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expkv-def}
\makeatletter
\ekvsetdef\circarcSetup{richard/circarc}
\ekvdefinekeys{richard/circarc}
  {%
     store   bend   = \circarc@bend
    ,store   radius = \circarc@radius
    ,initial radius = 1
    ,store   angle  = \circarc@angle
    ,store   style  = \circarc@style
    % counter-clockwise
    ,noval   ccw    = \def\circarc@rotdir{+}\def\circarc@benddir{right}
    % clockwise
    ,noval   cw     = \def\circarc@rotdir{-}\def\circarc@benddir{left}
    ,initial cw
    ,unknown noval  = \edef\circarc@bend{\unexpanded{#1}}
  }
% shortcoming in current version of exkpv-def, no interface to expkv's `\ekvlet`
% has been added, yet.
\ekvletkv{richard/circarc}{angle-}{richard/circarc}{angle}
\ekvletkv{richard/circarc}{angle+}{richard/circarc}{angle}
\ekvdefinekeys{richard/circarc}
  {%
     also code angle- = \def\circarc@sign{-}
    ,also code angle+ = \def\circarc@sign{+}
  }
% so that `angle -= 10` and `angle-=10` do the same thing
\ekvletkv{richard/circarc}{angle -}{richard/circarc}{angle-}
\ekvletkv{richard/circarc}{angle +}{richard/circarc}{angle+}
\newcount\circarc@elements
\newcount\circarc@current
\newcommand*\circarc@sign{}
\newcommand\circarc@count[2]{#1=\the\numexpr\ekvcsvloop{+1\@gobble}{#2}\relax}
\newcommand\circarc@once[1]{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}
\protected\def\circarc@smuggle\endgroup
  {%
    \expanded
      {%
        \endgroup
        \edef\noexpand\circarc@output
          {\noexpand\unexpanded{\circarc@once\circarc@output}}%
      }%
  }
\newcommand\circarc@eaddto[2]
  {\edef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}#2}}
\newcommand\circarc@epreto[2]
  {\edef#1{#2\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}
\newcommand\circarc[2][]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \circarcSetup{#1}%
      \let\circarc@startangle\circarc@angle
      \let\circarc@angle\@empty
      \let\circarc@sign\@empty
      \let\circarc@output\@empty
      \circarc@current=\z@
      \circarc@count\circarc@elements{#2}%
      \ekvparse\circarc@add@n@opts\circarc@add@w@opts{#2}%
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \circarc@output
  }
\newcommand\circarc@add@w@opts[2]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \let\circarc@angle\@empty
      \circarcSetup{#2}%
      \circarc@add{#1}%
      \circarc@smuggle
    \endgroup
    \advance\circarc@current by\@ne
  }
\newcommand\circarc@add@n@opts[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \circarc@add{#1}%
      \circarc@smuggle
    \endgroup
    \advance\circarc@current by\@ne
  }
\newcommand\circarc@add[1]
  {%
    \circarc@epreto\circarc@output
      {%
        \noexpand\node[\circarc@once\circarc@style]
          (circarc-\the\circarc@current)
          at (%
            \ifx\circarc@angle\@empty
              \fpeval
                {%
                  \circarc@startangle
                  \circarc@rotdir\circarc@current*360/\circarc@elements
                }%
            \else
              \ifx\circarc@sign\@empty
                \circarc@once\circarc@angle
              \else
                \fpeval
                  {%
                    \circarc@startangle
                    \circarc@rotdir\circarc@current*360/\circarc@elements
                    \circarc@sign\circarc@angle
                  }%
              \fi
            \fi
            :\circarc@once\circarc@radius
          )
          {\unexpanded{#1}};
      }%
    \circarc@eaddto\circarc@output
      {%
        \noexpand\draw[->]
          (circarc-\the\circarc@current)
          to[%
            bend \circarc@benddir
            \ifx\circarc@bend\@empty\else=\circarc@once\circarc@bend\fi
          ]
          (%
            circarc-%
            \ifnum\numexpr\circarc@current+\@ne=\circarc@elements
              0%
            \else
              \the\numexpr\circarc@current+\@ne\relax
            \fi
          );%
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \circarc[angle=90]
    {%
      Foo,Bar=150,Baz={radius=1.5,bend=15}
    }
  \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \circarc[radius=1.2,ccw]
      {
        Foo={angle=-15},Bar,Baz={style=draw},Bang={angle-=25}
      }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]